# TNS no listener error connecting to remote oracle database through VPN

Tags: oracle11g, listener, windows-7-x64, toad, tnsnames

I am using Windows 7 professional.  I have reloaded oracle client.  Up until two days ago I connected with no problem.  My company did a computer update and made a change in my VPN, but the help desk has been no help.  Team mate can connect with no issues with same tnsnames and sqlnet.  When trying to connect to the database via TOAD, Pl Sql Developer, Visual Stuido, or SSRS, I get TNS no listener error.  I have checked my TNSNames file.  The entry has not changed and is:  idwbcmip = 
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 165.136.98.57)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA = 
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SID = idwbcmip)
    )
  )

I have checked Sqlnet.ora and it is: SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES,LDAP, EZCONNECT)

TNSAdmin is set to correct path

I have tried to start a listener via lsnrctl and received a tns protocol adapter error.

I have contacted the host of the database to check listener, but if team mate can access, it is obviously turned on.

I have checked my services.  The only ones available are 
Oracle MTSRecovery Service  Started
OracleOraClient11g_home2CMAdmin won't start, can't find
OracleOraClient11ghome2CMan  won't start, can't find
OracleOraClient12Home1_34bitMTSRecoveryService won't start, can't find
OracleOraDb11g_home1ClrAgent  Started
OracltRemExecServiceV2 Started
OraClient11g_home2_OracleSchedulerExecutionAgent won't start, can't find

TNSPing gives tns no listener error

Our company provided a tunnel through our firewall to client company firewall.

At a loss on what else to check.

Comment: Excellent start.  This looks more like a network routing issue than an Oracle listener issue.  A couple more things you could try, to gather more data.  Try to `ping` the i.p. address of the host. Try a traceroute `tracert 165.136.98.57` that shows the hops that the traffic takes to reach the host.  Try a different network - e.g. share your phone's data - before connecting the VPN.  See if you can compare vpn config (and traceroute output) with your colleague that has it working.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried ping and TNSPing and get no listener error.  I cannot connect in any other way other than this VPN as the client does not accept any other connection.  Tracert is giving me Request Timed Out errors.  I will have a call in again to my help desk in the morning as I believe they made a change in the VPN that is affecting my connection, but they don't seem to agree with me.  Unfortunately our company does all the vpn configuration, and we have no control over it.  We are in the process of changing from one company to another and many things seem to get overlooked.